# Thousands separator thymeleaf: use apostrophe

Tags: formatting, numbers, thymeleaf, apostrophe

I'm using thymeleaf to render my views.
Is it possible to use ' (apostrophe) as a thousands seperator?
Example: What I want is to replace WHITESPACE in the following example with a Value for an apostrophe.

```
<span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(value, 5, 'WHITESPACE', 2, 'POINT' )}"
```

Is there a NumberPointType for apostrophe or another solution to achieve a formatting like this: **1'000.00**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dig into the sourcecode of `enum` `org.thymeleaf.util.NumberPointType` you will see the only available options with standard `#numbers.formatDecimal` are..

```
public enum NumberPointType {
    POINT("POINT"),
    COMMA("COMMA"),
    WHITESPACE("WHITESPACE"),
    NONE("NONE"),
    DEFAULT("DEFAULT");
...
```

So my preference for you is to create a custom method inside your own code, for example as a `bean` or a `utility object`, and create your own function to format the decimal as you wish.

**Update**

```
public class UIutil {

/**
 * Formats a BigInteger to a thousand grouped String
 * @param number
 * @return
 */
public static String formatNumber (BigInteger number) {
    return String.format("%,d", number);
}
```

}

Assign:

```
context.setVariable("formatter", new UIutil());
```

Call:

```
th:text="${formatter.formatNumber(value)}"
```

Comment: okey thanks. how do you register the custom object / custom implementation to thymeleaf?

Comment: Create a utility bean and access like @beanName or add the utility object to the model attribut.

Comment: Ok thanks. I assigned a util object to the context on which I call a static mehtod.

Answer (score 0):

In my case. use this.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
public class CommonUtil {
    public static final String DOT = ".";

    public static String comma(BigDecimal n) {
        return comma(String.valueOf(n));
    }

    public static String comma(double n) {
        return comma(String.valueOf(n));
    }

    public static String comma(String n) {
        try {
            List<String> h = Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(n, CommonUtil.DOT));
            String decimal = h.size() == 2 ?
                "." + h.get(1) :
                "";

            return comma(Integer.parseInt(h.get(0))) + decimal;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("NaN <{}>", n);
            return n;
        }
    }

    public static String comma(int n) {
        return NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(n);
    }
}
```